# Why does string shuffle stop working after 10 characters in the string?

Tags: c++, debugging

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string cardsShuffle(string orig_seq){
    string choice;
    int random = 0;
    string shuffled_seq;
    int orig_len = orig_seq.length();
    
    while(orig_len > shuffled_seq.length()){
        random = rand() % orig_seq.length();
        
        while(random % 2 != 0){
            random = rand() % orig_seq.length();
        }
        
        choice = orig_seq.substr(random,2);
        orig_seq.erase(random,random+2);
        shuffled_seq = shuffled_seq + choice;
        
    }
    return shuffled_seq;
}

int main()
{
    string orig_seq;
    cout << "Enter orig_seq: \n";
    cin >> orig_seq;
    cout << cardsShuffle(orig_seq);
  
    return 0;
}
```

This works perfectly until you try it with 10 characters then nothing is ever returned and the program just exist normally after going through the function as it normally does, except I can't figure out why it just decides it's done

Comment: Did you single-step through your code with a debugger? What did you find?

Comment: You might want to learn about [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Comment: When orig_seq is empty orig_seq.length() returns 0 and you try to mod by zero but division by zero is not allowed.

Comment: Why are you using orig_len as the condition of the while loop if the length of that string changes inside the loop? Did you mean to use orig_seq.length() in the while condition loop?

Comment: Jerry, because if I didn't the program cuts itself short, it will end prematurely, I originally started with that but it doesn't work for any size, now the program only breaks if it goes over 10 which is the confusing part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get a normal exit, I get "Floating point exception(core dumped)".

The [`erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) function does not have the parameters you think it does - like `substr`, the second is the length, not the "one past the end" index.
(`std::string` has a peculiar interface, as it was created long before the standard collections were added.)
So you remove `random+2` characters, and the longer the string, the greater the chance that you end up erasing too many characters, and that will lead to undefined behaviour.

Change that line to

```
orig_seq.erase(random, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, man you made my day. I honestly don't know why I keep forgetting that because as I was checking your comment I have a whole reference page for .erase() open and was still convincing myself that I did it right :/
Thanks again so much for your help!